# Parsing procedure calls for a toy language

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, recursive-descent

I have a certain toy language that defines, amongst others, procedures and procedure calls, using EBNF syntax:

```
program = procedure, {procedure} ;
procedure = "procedure", NAME, bracedblock ;
bracedBlock = "{" , statementlist , "}" ;
statementlist = statement, { statement } ;
statement = define | if | while | call | // others omitted for brevity  ;
define = NAME, "=", expression, ";"
if = "if", conditionalblock, "then", bracedBlock, "else", bracedBlock
call = "call" , NAME, ";" ;
// other definitions omitted for brevity
```

A tokeniser for a program in this language has been implemented, and returns a vector of tokens.

Now, parsing said program *without* the procedure calls, is fairly straightforward: one can define a recursive descent parser using the above grammar directly, and simply parse through the tokens. Some further notes:

1. Each procedure may call *any* other procedure *except* itself, directly or indirectly (i.e. no recursion), and these need not necessarily be in the order of appearance in the source code (i.e. `B` may be defined after `A`, and `A` may call `B`, or vice versa).
2. Procedure names need to be unique, and 'reserved keywords' may be used as variable/procedure names.
3. Whitespace does not matter, at least amongst tokens of different type: similar to C/C++.
4. There is no scoping rule: all variables are global.
5. The concept of a 'line number' is important: each statement has one or more line numbers associated with it: `define` statements have only 1 line number each, for instance, whereas an `if` statement, which is itself a parent of *two* statement lists, has multiple line numbers. For instance:

```
LN      CODE
        procedure A {
1.         a = 5;
2.         b = 7;
3.         c = 3;
4. 5.      if (b < c) then { call C; } else {
6.               call B;
           }

        procedure B {
7.         d = 5;
8.         while (d > 2) { 
9.             d = d + 1; }
        }

        procedure C {
10.          e = 10; 
11.          f = 8;
12.         call B;
        }
```

6. Line numbers are *continuous* throughout the program; only procedure definitions and the `else` keyword aren't assigned line numbers. The line numbers are defined by grammar, rather than their position in source code: for instance, consider 'lines' `4` and `5`.
7. There are some relationships that need to be set in a database given each statement and its line number, variables used, variables *set*, and child containers. **This is a key consideration**.

My question is therefore this: how can I parse these function calls, maintain the integrity of the line numbers, and set the relationships?

I have considered the 'OS' way of doing things: upon encounter of a procedure call, look ahead for a procedure that matches said called procedure, parse the callee, and unroll the call stack back to the caller. However, this ruins the line number ordering: if the above program were to be parsed this way, `C` would have line numbers `6` to `8` inclusive, rather than `10` to `12` inclusive.

Another solution is to parse the entire program once *in order*, maintain a toposort of procedure calls, and then parse a second time by following said toposort. This is problematic because of implementation details.

Is there a possibly better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's always tempting to try to completely process a program text in a single on-line pass. Unfortunately, it is practically never the simplest solution. Trying to do everything at once in a linear progression results in a kind of spaghetti of intertwined computations, and making it all work almost always involves unnecessary restrictions on the language which will later prove to be unfortunate.

So I'd encourage you to reconsider some of your design decisions. If you use the parser just to build up some kind of structural representation of the program -- whether it's an *abstract syntax tree* or a vector of *three-address code*, or some other alternative -- and then do further processing in a series of single-purpose passes over that structural representations, you'll likely find that the code is:

- much simpler, because computations don't have to be intermingled;
- more general, because each pass can be done in the most convenient order rather than restricting inputs to fit a linear ordering;
- more readable and more maintainable.

Persisting data structures over multiple passes might increase storage requirements slightly. But the structures are unlikely to occupy enough storage that this will be noticeable. And it probably will not increase the computation time; indeed, it might even reduce the time because the individual passes are simpler and easier to optimise.